# nex-auth signup problem . after signup can't see profile without signin

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, nodemailer, next-auth

I setup login and signup and also token, verify with next_auth in next.js . but problem is after sign-Up  user have to verify from Gmail and then it's show verify success after that user should see profile page but  can't see profile without login . please help me or give me a demo code .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy96C.png)